# scp error in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, scp

When I'm connecting to server from my local desktop - it is connecting.

When I'm using `scp` over port 22 - have timeout.

I'm using following commands to connect via SSH:

```
ssh -p 22 user1@192.168.12.10
```

and it is connected and I can log in

After that I want to copy the file from the server IP `192.168.12.10`:

```
scp -P 22 /home/user1/Desktop/1.txt user2@192.168.12.10:/home/user2/Desktop
```

Her I'm getting the following error

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.12.10 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

In Ubuntu 10.04 everything works fine.

I am getting problem for Ubuntu 12.04 only. I can connect to server using `ssh` and I cannot copy the file using `scp`.

What is the problem?

Comment: As I understand you can copy via `scp` using Ubuntu 10.04, and cannot copy from **same server** using Ubuntu 12.04. Am I correct?

Comment: yes your right exactly I need a solution please

Answer (score 1):

While `-p` is the valid option to specify the port to connect to the `ssh` command, it is not for the `scp` command.

The `-P` (capital P) is the parameter to specify the port to connect to the `scp` command.

The `-p` parameter (with any value after it) is used to ask `scp` to preserve modification times, access times, and modes from the original file. Like the `-p` option of the local copy command, `cp`.

By the way, **22** beeing the default SSH port, no need to explicitly specify it to the command line.

Comment: I have replaced the command (small p to capital P) till same error

Answer (score 0):

Add the ssh 192.168.xx.xx subnet 255.255.xxx.xxx to the host.allow file